# How to avoid blocking read() from named pipe after it closes

Tags: c, linux, named-pipes

I have two processes created with named pipe. The writer process writes a message using write(), and the reader process reads the message with read(). I noticed that read() blocks when the writer closes the pipe. Is that possible to let writer process sends EOF before closing the pipe so that the reader will not be blocked?

Comment: If the writer closes its end of the pipe, `read` on the other end should return `0`. Can you please show your reader code, or at least try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the reader to show us what you do?

Comment: `read()` returns 0 when the last file desriptor on the write end has been closed. The [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html) remarks that after a fork() the processes should `close()` unused file descriptors, because leaving them open would not cause EOF on the reader side resp. SIGPIPE on the writer side as one would expect when the actual writers/readers close the pipe fd. Could that be an issue?

Answer (score 3):

Not... It's not possible to send an `EOF` because `EOF` is nothing that maps to something sent over the channel.  `EOF` condition (yes, it's a condition, not something you receive or send over the channel) means there's no more data to `read(2)` and it's got by a process by making `read(2)` to return 0 characters read.  As many reads you do in `EOF` condition, they will return a value of `0` meaning there's no more data.

By the way, pipes block readers when there's no data available, but, as the writer is still there to send more data, there's no EOF condition.  By design, pipes block readers when there's no data available (but a writer still has the pipe open) and block writers when there's no more space to put data in the fifo (this happens when there are readers with the fifo open, but none of them is reading)   As you see it's a feature, not a bug.

If you want to make `read(2)` non blocking and get `0` when there's no data available, you can `open(2)` with `O_NONBLOCK` flag (or do it later, with the `fcntl(2)` system call), that will make `read(2)` to return immediately with the available data (even if there's no data available) but it has a drawback: then you cannot distinguish a fifo with no data available (it has not been written) from an actual `EOF` (the writer has closed its side) as both will return with `0` as result.

By the way, I don't like to use the `EOF` constant when talking about *end of file* conditions, because it adds to the confusion of its definition.  `EOF` is the value returned by `getchar(3)` on an *end of file* condition, but it's not a `char`  (if you check the definition of `getchar(3)` you will discover it's defined as `int` and not `char`, this is to add the `EOF` condition to the whole range of possible `char` values --- so, there are 257 possible values returned from `getchar(3)`, `0-256` for data, and `EOF` for *end of file condition*)

If you want writers to signal *end of file* they have to `close(2)` the fifo and reopen it.

Answer (score 1):

When the writer closes the pipe, the reader will not block, even if it *was* blocked (e.g. it will wake up).  The read call will return 0 indicating EOF on the pipe.  The reader should do:

```
rlen = read(pipefd,buf,sizeof(buf));
if (rlen <= 0)
    break;
```

Are you checking your return codes?

In the writer, if the reader has closed the pipe prematurely (e.g. it aborted), the writer will get a return from write of -1 and errno set to EPIPE.  It can also get SIGPIPE.

See man 7 pipe ...